# Is there a transformation in TikZ that transforms the positioning of nodes, but not the nodes itself?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm drawing some category theory diagrams like these:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    \newcommand{\dual}{\draw (-2,-1) node[below] {$X$} arc (180:0:2cm) node[below] {$^*X$};}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \dual
        \node {Evaluation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[yscale=-1]
            \dual
        \end{scope}
        \node {Coevaluation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since the actual picture is more complicated (decorations) and I'm drawing several such pictures which are all just reflections of each other, I'd like to define the picture once and then have the others with a scope and scaling, as shown in the example. But obviously, the positions of the nodes should now be "above" and not "below". Is there a "nice" way to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea. I don't know if it could be applicable to your scenario, but if it is, it is the simplest one: do not use `above` nor `below`. Instead, let the node to be placed "over" the edges, and give it a white backround to hide part of the curve. I.e:

```
\newcommand{\dual}{\draw (-2,-1) node[fill=white] {$X$} arc (180:0:2cm) node[fill=white] {$^*X$};}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \dual
        \node {Evaluation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}[yscale=-1]
            \dual
        \end{scope}
        \node {Coevaluation};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Which produces:

[image: Result]

Comment: Clever workaround, one nearly can't see the difference!